# Forcing an Encoder's UnkeyedEncodingContainer to only contain one type of value

Tags: swift, encoding, protocols

As part of a custom `Encoder`, I am coding an `UnkeyedEncodingContainer`. However, the specific format I am making it for asks that all elements of an array be of the same type. Specifically, arrays can contain :

- Integers one same size
- Floats or Doubles
- Other arrays (not necessarily all containing the same kinds of elements)
- Objects
  Here is the type of answer I need : The basis of an `UnkeyedEncodingContainer` implementation that conforms to the protocol, and enforces that all elements be of one same type among the above specified ones.

As requested, here are examples of things that should or should not be encodable :

```
var valid1 = []
var valid2 = [3, 3, 5, 9]
var valid3 = ["string", "array"]

var invalid1 = [3, "test"]
var invalid2 = [5, []]
var invalid3 = [[3, 5], {"hello" : 3}]
// These may not all even be valid Swift arrays, they are only
// intended as examples
```

As an example, here is the best I have come up with, which does not work :

---

The `UnkeyedEncodingContainer` contains a function, checkCanEncode, and an instance variable, `ElementType` :

```swift
var elementType : ElementType {
    if self.count == 0 {
        return .None
    } else {
        return self.storage[0].containedType
    }
}


func checkCanEncode(_ value : Any?, compatibleElementTypes : [ElementType]) throws {
    guard compatibleElementTypes.contains(self.elementType) || self.elementType == .None else {
        let context = EncodingError.Context(
            codingPath: self.nestedCodingPath,
            debugDescription: "Cannot encode value to an array of \(self.elementType)s"
        )
        throw EncodingError.invalidValue(value as Any, context)
    }
}
// I know the .None is weird and could be replaced by an optional,
// but it is useful as its rawValue is 0. The Encoder has to encode
// the rawValue of the ElementType at some point, so using an optional
// would actually be more complicated
```

Everything is then encoded as a contained `singleValueContainer` :

```swift
func encode<T>(_ value: T) throws where T : Encodable {
    let container = self.nestedSingleValueContainer()
    try container.encode(value)
    try checkCanEncode(value, compatibleElementTypes: [container.containedType])
}
// containedType is an instance variable of SingleValueContainer that is set
// when a value is encoded into it
```

But this causes an issue when it comes to `nestedContainer` and `nestedUnkeyedContainer` : (used for stored dictionaries and arrays respectively)

```swift
// This violates the protocol, this function should not be able to throw
func nestedContainer<NestedKey>(keyedBy keyType: NestedKey.Type) throws -> KeyedEncodingContainer<NestedKey> where NestedKey : CodingKey {
    let container = KeyedContainer<NestedKey>(
        codingPath: self.nestedCodingPath,
        userInfo: self.userInfo
    )
    try checkCanEncode(container, compatibleElementTypes: [.Dictionary])
    self.storage.append(container)
    return KeyedEncodingContainer(container)
}
```

As you can see, since I need `checkCanEncode` to know whether it is even possible to create a `NestedContainer` in the first place (because if the array already has stuff inside that aren't dictionaries, then adding dictionaries to it is invalid), I **have** to make the function throw. But this breaks the `UnkeyedEncodingContainer` protocol which demands non-throwing versions.

But I can't just handle the error inside the function ! If something tries to put an array inside an array of integers, it **must** fail. Therefore this is an invalid solution.

---

Additional remarks :

Checking after having encoded the values already feels sketchy, but checking only when producing the final encoded payload is **definitely** a violation of the "No Zombies" principle (*fail as soon as the program enters an invalid state*) which I would rather avoid. However if no better solution is possible I may accept it as a last resort.

One other solution I have thought about is encoding the array as a dictionary with numbered keys, since dictionaries in this format may contain mixed types. However this is likely to pose decoding issues, so once again, it is a last resort.

---

**You will be advised not to edit other people’s questions. If you have edits to suggest please do so in the comments, otherwise mind your own business**

Comment: Again, a `check can encode` at runtime is pointless. Instead of `Any`. use a generic constrained to `Encodable` (`<T : Encodable>`)  then the check will be performed at **compile time**

Comment: @vadian the constrain has to be dynamic though, and encoding containers do not conform to encodable. It isn’t simply a matter of enforcing that the elements are all encodable. They have to be **the same** type. But which type they are has a few possibilities.

Comment: The Swift design philosophy encourages you to answer as many *type questions* as possible at compile time. To start with `Any` is a bad choice.

Comment: @vadian I am aware of that, if you have a suggestion of a compile-time solution I invite you to post an answer, I have been unable to formulate one so far. You will also find that ```Any``` is only used here to include the value in the error message regardless of its type.

Comment: I still don't get it. `JSONEncoder` can only encode types which conforms to `Encodable`, period. `[String:Any]` or even `Any` is not supported.

Comment: @vadian ```Encodable``` is not enough of a requirement. The problem is not that ```UnkeyedEncodingContainer``` may ever actually contain ```Any```, the problem is that ```[3, "toast", {"hello" : 25}]``` is a valid JSON array but it is completely unacceptable to this format.

Thus even an array of ```Encodable``` is not always actually encodable in this format.

Comment: As I said in one of your previous questions, a generic array `[T] where T : Encodable` throws an error if the type is not an homogenous array of an Encodable type.

Comment: My apologies @vadian, I had not fully understood what you meant. This is a good working start, however there remains one problem : ```KeyedEncodingContainer``` and ```UnkeyedEncodingContainer``` are **not** ```Encodable``` yet I also need to be able to accept arrays of them. If you can write an answer that reconciles this one problem however I may be able to grant you the bounty ! I don't think I can grant it to comments.

Comment: I think the confusion here is the claim that `[String:Any]` is a legal entry. That's not really true. It's `[String: EncodableByThisScheme]`. But Any isn't really the problem. The problem is that Encoder is very inflexible in how it handles formats, and was pretty narrowly designed to handle PropertyList and JSON.

Comment: Just to be clear, `[3, []]` would be invalid? But `[["a"], [1]]` would be valid? (It would be helpful to include some test cases.) Preventing `[3, []]` feels very hard.

Comment: For me it's still unclear what is the purpose of the nested containers. Please add two concrete examples what you want to encode.

Comment: @vadian The point isn't what needs to be encoded, the point is how to enforce encoding rules. I think this example captures what's being discussed (Crysambrosia, please correct if I misunderstand): https://gist.github.com/rnapier/460318a4293c4ae6ecc83326c086cde5  This encoder function should fail. (Probably ideally at compile-time, but that's almost certainly impossible, but at least at runtime, which may also be at least pretty tricky…) Replace "JSONEncoder" with a custom Encoder implementation that writes its own format.

Comment: Can arrays be empty in this format?

Comment: @RobNapier Yes, arrays may be empty. Also, you are correct, this should fail. However vadian is right that using an internal array of one encodable as storage is a partial solution. The only remaining problem is nested containers

Comment: @RobNapier I have added examples of valid and invalid things to encode

Comment: `valid4` is invalid because the third array is heterogenous.

Comment: @vadian do you mean invalid in terms of swift ? It is valid in terms of the encoding format, it is an array of arrays, which is permitted.

Comment: No it’s not, the third array is an array of dictionaries and the second dictionary is `[String:Any]` which is not supported and which contradicts your requirement of *the same type*.

Comment: Actually this is completely fine for this format. Dictionaries may contain mixed types, arrays may not. Basically, arrays encode only one byte specifying what they contain, while each value in a dictionary has its own type marker. If you look at the first paragraph, arrays may contain ```[String:Encodable]``` dictionaries.

Comment: `Any` is not `Encodable`. `[String:String]` is , `[String:Double]` is, even  `[String: [String:[String:[String:[Double]]]]]` is but `Any` is not. The mentioned dictionary contains a `String` value and an `Int` value. In terms of Swift this is `Any`.

Comment: @vadian That is actually a **big** problem with Swift's encoding then, which I did not foresee. Having tested it myself I can hardly believe it, it means data cannot be decoded to generic dictionary containers and absolutely requires an object with the right properties. I will do my best to work around that but it really seems like a huge flaw.

Comment: @vadian I am trying out your idea of using a ```[T] where T : Encodable``` array, however that syntax is not valid and I am having trouble finding a valid equivalent. Any suggestions ?

Comment: These are the two sides of a strong typed language. The encoder can do a lot of hard work on your behalf but it must know *all* static types and the collection types must be homogenous. Actually you can simply write `try JSONEncoder().encode(foo)`. The compiler will complain if `foo` including the entire contents doesn't conform to `Encodable` and it will also detect – and doesn't allow you to encode – heterogenous collection types.

Comment: @vadian Provided that information I think my issue is completely unsolvable in the way I wanted to. Maybe you could say it's an XY problem in a way. Thank you for your help ! I have posted my best alternative idea as an answer, if you think it could also be improved please don't hesitate to comment

Comment: If no one can come up with anything I will be forced to accept my own answer as the correct one, and grant @vadian the bounty for his help in realizing there was no other alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless anyone has a better idea, here is the best I could come up with :

- Do not enforce that all elements be of the same type inside the `UnkeyedEncodingContainer`
- If all elements are the same type, encode it as an array
- If elements have varying types, encode it as a dictionary with integers as keys

This is completely fine as far as the encoding format goes, has minimal costs and only slightly complicates decoding (check whether keys contain integers) and greatly widens how many different Swift object will be compatible with the format.

*Note : Remember that the "real" encoding step where the data is generated is not actually part of the protocol. That is where I am proposing the shenanigans should take place*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this helps you but in Swift you can *overload* functions. This means that you can declare functions with the same signature but with different parameter types or constraints. The compiler will take always the right choice. It's much more efficient than a type check at runtime.

The first method is called if the array conforms to `Encodable`

```
func encode<T: Encodable>(object: [T]) throws -> Data {
        return try JSONEncoder().encode(object)
}
```

Otherwise the second method is called. If the array cannot even be encoded with `JSONSerialization` you can add custom encoding logic.

```
func encode<T>(object: [T]) throws -> Data {
    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object)
    } catch {
        // do custom encoding and return Data
        return try myCustomEncoding(object)
    }
}
```

This example

```
let array = [["1":1, "2":2]]
try encode(object: array)
```

calls the first method.

On the other hand this – even if the actual type is not heterogenous – calls the second method

```
let array : [[String:Any]] = [["1":1, "2":2]]
try encode(object: array)
```

Comment: I did know about overloading (it is extensively used elsewhere in the encoder), the bit about ```JSONSerialization``` is interesting though. I'm not sure it would be helpful for an actual application, since I will be defining the necessary objects once the decoder is finished (```[String:Any]``` dictionaries were mostly intended in the question as placeholders for real objects). But it is useful to know that I could encode to and decode from "generic" containers for testing purposes.